# MySQL Table Convrted to utf-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, persian

I had an old table with latin1 charset. Using phpmyadmin, I convert it to utf-8 
After that, when I read data with php, my data shows as ???? ????? question marks

my page charset is utf-8 there is no problem with my php , and i also tried :

```
@mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db);
@mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $db);
@mysqli_query("SET character_set_client = utf8 ",$db);
@mysqli_query("SET character_set_results = utf8 ",$db) ;
@mysqli_query("SET character_set_connection = utf8 ",$db);
```

before any query

seems doesn't work, still showing as ???? ??????

there is no problem for new records, but old records are not readable

they are stored in db like : ØºÙ„Ø§Ù…ÛŒ

Is there any way to retrieve those old data?

Answer (score 0):

What I used to do is go on the command line

`mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 ... > file.sql`

then convert file.sql to UTF (using ICONV or any other option) then alter the table's charset and use

`mysql --default-character-set=utf8 < file.sql`

You could just use the export option from phpMyAdmin and converting like in the above example, change the charset on the table from phpMyAdmin and then import it again.

I usually did a backup before doing this cause mistakes happen but its very simple